# What are the parameters for Aforge's Grayscale filter?

Tags: .net, image-processing, aforge

I am using Aforge.Net to do some image processing and I'm having trouble understanding [the Grayscale filter](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/d7196dc6-8176-4344-a505-e7ade35c1741.htm). Specifically the three mandatory red/green/blue coefficient constructor parameters.

To my understanding (from doing image segmentation research eight years ago) grayscaling is an operation that shouldn't take *any* parameters. You take an image, and you extract the **luminescence** channel, that's all.

So what are these parameters, and how do I simply extract luminescence?

**Update:**
I should clarify what I'm trying to do. I am trying to automate a process which I can do manually in GIMP. In GIMP I can apply a threshold to any image and it operates on the luminescence histogram to produce a binary image, however in Aforge the Threshold filter works only on grayscale images. So how would I replicate my manual process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: GIMP desaturate dialog box]

When you convert to grayscale like this (see screenshot) in GIMP, it is calling this on each pixel:

```
gint luminosity = GIMP_RGB_LUMINANCE (s[RED], s[GREEN], s[BLUE]) + 0.5;
```

And a look at the source of gimprgb.c shows it is indeed using these values:

```
#define GIMP_RGB_LUMINANCE_RED    (0.2126)
#define GIMP_RGB_LUMINANCE_GREEN  (0.7152)
#define GIMP_RGB_LUMINANCE_BLUE   (0.0722)
```

I compared the output image from GIMP to one produced by AForge using these params:

```
var filter = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.Grayscale(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722);
```

and they appear identical.

**UPDATE:**

It appears that with the Threshold tool though, GIMP is taking a shortcut and simply taking the max of R,G or B. From threshold.c:

```
if (tr->color)
            {
              value = MAX (s[RED], s[GREEN]);
              value = MAX (value, s[BLUE]);

              value = (value >= tr->low_threshold &&
                       value <= tr->high_threshold ) ? 255 : 0;
            }
          else
            {
              value = (s[GRAY] >= tr->low_threshold &&
                       s[GRAY] <= tr->high_threshold) ? 255 : 0;
            }
```

So that is probably why you are getting different results.

**UPDATE 2:**

The various "convert to grayscale" methods included in .Net and elsewhere seem to all take averages or use some variation on the brightness or luminosity numbers mentioned above. I think reproducing the max value version used by GIMP Threshold will have to be done by hand. I adapted some of the fast (though unsafe) code found [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/660/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale) to produce this:

```
public static Bitmap ColorToGrayscaleWithMax(Bitmap original)
{
    unsafe
    {
        Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        BitmapData originalData = original.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        BitmapData newData = newBitmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height),
            ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

        //Set bytes per pixel
        int colorBytesPerPixel = 3;
        int grayBytesPerPixel = 1;

        for (int y = 0; y < original.Height; y++)
        {
            //get the data from the original image
            byte* oRow = (byte*)originalData.Scan0 + (y * originalData.Stride);

            //get the data from the new image
            byte* nRow = (byte*)newData.Scan0 + (y * newData.Stride);

            for (int x = 0; x < original.Width; x++)
            {
                //create the grayscale pixel by finding the max color
                byte grayScale = Math.Max(oRow[x * colorBytesPerPixel], oRow[x * colorBytesPerPixel + 1]);
                grayScale = Math.Max(grayScale, oRow[x * colorBytesPerPixel + 2]);

                //set the new image's pixel to the grayscale version
                nRow[x * grayBytesPerPixel] = grayScale; //B
            }
        }

        //unlock the bitmaps, finish
        newBitmap.UnlockBits(newData);
        original.UnlockBits(originalData);

        return newBitmap;
    }
}
```

And then you can use it as such:

```
var colorImage = AForge.Imaging.Image.FromFile(@"c:\temp\images\colorImage.png");
var preThresholdImage = ColorToGrayscaleWithMax(colorImage);
var filter = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.Threshold(100);
Bitmap bwImage = filter.Apply(preThresholdImage);
bwImage.Save(@"c:\temp\images\bwImage.png");
```

I ran it on a couple of images and compared with the ones produced manually with GIMP and they finally appeared identical.

Comment: Thanks a lot, these numbers still don't get me the exact results I'm seeing in GIMP but I suspect now the issue lies in me misunderstanding how the GIMP threshold filter works when applied to color images. I will start another thread for that if I can't figure it out.

Comment: I also got different results. Updated answer to reflect that the threshold tool not actually calculating "luminosity" but simply max R/G/B.

Comment: woah, interesting (And also actually explains the results I'm seeing) any advice on how to implement this with Aforge (resulting in a Grayscale image)? I suppose I can track down the Grayscale filter source code...but I wonder if there's a better approach.

Comment: Photoshop, Imagemagick, etc. all seem to implement a more sophisticated conversion. Gimp appears to be the odd one out, so have to implement by hand. (Updated)

Answer (score 1):

The RGB to grayscale conversion needs weighted sum on RGB channels. And the measure of color luminescence includes an non-linear transform called [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction). It is also a weighted sum, but on `R^gamma`, `G^gamma`, and `B^gamma` respectively. More formulas are described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Colorimetric_.28luminance-perserving.29_conversion_to_grayscale).

Comment: Kindof over my head there. So what do these values affect and what do I set them to for my grayscale image to just be equivalent to simply extracting luminescence?

Comment: Y = .2126 * R^gamma + .7152 * G^gamma + .0722 * B^gamma for standard brightness or 0.2989*R+ 0.5870 * G + 0.1140 * B for perceived option is used most often.

Comment: Still not quite sure, what this formula represents, is this how luminescence of a pixel is calculated? Are you saying that something like the Photoshop or GIMP grayscale filter simply has some hard-coded values?

Comment: Yes this is how luminescence of a pixel is calculated with different methods. R,G,B represent the intensity values in the original RGB image at 3 channels divide by 255, so they all fall into the range of (0,1)